# jQuery Deferred Ajax, JavaScript scope issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but it's not working (live example at http://jsfiddle.net/QtjaG/):

```
$.resx = function() {
    var result = this;

    return $.get("/", function() {
        result = "yo";
    });
};

var labels;

$.resx.call(labels).then(function() {
    console.log(labels);
});
```

Since `$.resx.call(labels)` should set the `this` context within `$.resx()` to `labels`, shouldn't `console.log(labels)` log `yo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function (the "$.resx" function), you do set "result" to refer to the same thing that "labels" refers to.  However, in the callback from "$.get()" you then set it to "yo". That string constant "yo" is a *different* value than "labels", which was actually not initialized to anything in the first place.  There's no way in JavaScript to have a *reference to a reference*; if "labels" had been defined to have some value:

```
var labels = "this is a string";
```

then "result" would end up being *another* reference to that string. However, strings are immutable, so from inside the "$.get()" success handler you can't change that string.

Try this:

```
$.resx = function() {
    var result = this;

    return $.get("/", function() {
        result[0] = "yo";
    });
};

var labels = ["not yo"];

$.resx.call(labels).then(function() {
    console.log(labels[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you console.log(this), you get window. That's because your function's scope is global. I think what you're looking for is the "apply" method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply. However I don't think you need it because you can do the following simply below. The callBack function's closure will wrap around the "labels" reference. And because functions are first-class objects, you can pass them in directly as delegates and call them like callBack(x);

```
$.resx = function(callBack) {      
    return $.get("/", function() {       
        callBack("yo");
    });  
};

var labels;

$.resx(function(response){
    labels = response;  
});
```